# Am I doing this right? Removing items from python list - is there room for optimization?

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have 2 lists. I want to remove all items from list which contain strings from second list. Now, I am using classical 2 loop approach, 1st I loop over copy of main list and then for every item i check if it contains any strings from 2nd list. Then I delete the item if string is found. And I can end the 2nd loop with break, since no more lookup is needed (we're gonna remove this line anyway). This works just fine - as you can see, I am iterating over copy of list, so removing elements is not a problem.

Here is the code:

```
    intRemoved = 0

    sublen = len(mylist) + 1
    halflen = sublen / 2

    for i, line in enumerate(mylist[:], 1):
        for item in REM:
            if item.encode('utf8').upper() in line.text.encode('utf8').upper():
                if i < halflen:
                    linepos = i
                else:
                    linepos = (sublen - i) * -1

                mylist.remove(line)
                intRemoved += 1
                break
```

Now, I need data how many lines I removed (intRemoved) and position in the list (from beginning of list or end of list, that's why it splits in half). Positive numbers indicate removed line position from the beginning of the file, negative from end.

Ahh, yes, and I am ignoring the case. That's why there is .upper().

Now, since I am in no way pro, I just need to know if I am doing it right, performance-wise? Am I doing something that's bad for performance? Is there a way to optimize this?

Thanx,
D.

Comment: Best place to ask optimization problems would be in codereview.stackexchange

Comment: My advises: normalise the lists before comparison (uppercase). Sorting can also help, not sure.

Comment: (1) linepos appears to be calculated but never used (2) `break` means premature (3) get it working before you consider optimisation!

Comment: I am using it later in the code, but it is not relevant to this case

Comment: (1) `linepos` appears to be calculated but never used. (2) What is `subSrt`? (3)get it working before you consider optimisation!

Comment: 1) I didnt' poste the whole code since it doesn't concern this example. It is used but not in this example, wanted to make it as simple as possible. 2) it is error while copy/paste, should be mylist, I edited it. 3) it works, sorry for error in example.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been said, probably you should be looking in codereview. Anyhow, I am pretty sure using `sets` and `intersection` operation is going to be much faster.

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: Thanx for the link, good to learn something. But from what I've read, I am not sure sets are good to use in this case - I don't have elements that are the same in both lists, I am looking for any part of element in list1 that list2 contains, i.e. list1 "this is an example" list2 "is an"...

Comment: `matching_words = [(index, string1, string2) for number,string1 in enumerate(a, 1) for string2 in b if ((string1.upper() in string2.upper()) or (string2.upper() in string.upper()))]`

Comment: Try that. If you have two list `a,b` composed of strings that snippet is enough for finding the common occurences and give them back to you in the form `[index (in list1), ocurrence, ocurrence]`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `encode` is unnecessary. Calling `upper` each time is not ideal. Coping the list for iterating is expensive. Removing is more expensive, since one have to search for the element and shifting elements. Counting  `intRemoved` is not the best way, either.

```
sublen = len(subsSrt) + 1
halflen = sublen / 2
filtered_list = []
rem_upper = [item.upper() for item in REM]
for i, line in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    text = line.text.upper()
    if any(item in text for item in rem_upper):
        if i < halflen:
            linepos = i
        else:
            linepos = (sublen - i) * -1
    else:
        filtered_list.append(line)
intRemoved = len(mylist) - len(filtered_list)
```

Comment: Don't you mean: `rem_upper = [item.upper() for item in REM]` with parenthesis?

Comment: Cool, thanx, I just tested and processing time went from 1.27 seconds to 0.24.... Just one thing - Is there a way to know which item in rem_upper was found? In my old code I would have used "item"....

Comment: If you need `item`, you should use a second loop.